# Нужно ли делать редирект со старого url на новый?

Tags: seo

Переписываю один проект. В ходе рефакторинга многие url пришлось изменить.
Возникает вопрос - нужно ли всем старым url'ам делать редирект на новые, именно с позиции Гугла?
Урлов, мягко говоря, много и я бы не стал заморачиваться, но где-то от кого-то слышал, что непременно надо ставить редиректы, иначе разгневаешь поисковики.
Хочется прояснить раз и навсегда - делать или нет, быть или не быть?

Comment: Редиректы надо делать обязательно, если не хотите потерять позиции сайта в поиске. Это раз. Два - это нужно сначала узнать, была ли для данного сайта seo-раскрутка. Если да, надо обязательно на тех страницах, на которые например, были куплены ссылки, поставить "правильный" редирект (ни в коем случае не 404).

Comment: В общем позиция такая: если это Ваш сайт и на нём реклама, то делать редиректы, иначе потеряете доход. Если не Ваш сайт и Вам за это не платят, то можно и не делать. Если Вам за это платят, то делать обязательно с проверкой по SEO (вдруг до Вас заказчик вложил 100т.р. на SEO, а Вы ему сейчас всё порушите - мало того, что не заплатят, еще и должны останетесь).

Answer (score 11):

Поисковики не "разгневаются", просто вы потеряете те страницы, что уже проиндексированы, а новые будут индексироваться какое-то неопределённое время. В итоге сайт просядет в поиске.
Ну и не стоит забывать про пользователей, ведь ради них, в принципе, всё сео и делается. Вряд ли они обрадуются, если попадут на несуществующую страницу из закладок или поиска.

Я рекомендую делать редиректы (и сам их всегда делаю) - это не так сложно, как восстанавливать позиции. [Гугл](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en) и [Яндекс](https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/recommendations/changing-site-structure.xml?lang=ru) со мной согласны.

В помощи Яндекса написано важное уточнение:

> Если же меняется не только структура сайта, но и его тематика, то вам необходимо настроить сервер таким образом, чтобы прежние страницы отдавали в заголовке код HTTP 404.

Скорее всего, к случаю, описанному в вопросе,оно не относится, но помнить об этом нужно.

Comment: Если указать 404, можно потерять "купленные" ссылки, так что с осторожностью это надо делать.

Answer (score 1):

Еще нужно уточнить

Нужно использовать **301 редирект** а не 302, иначе ссылки которые ведут на старые URL’s не передадут вес на новые URL’s.

Обязательно актуализируйте файл **sitemap.xml** (sitemap_index.xml) и отправьте на принудительное сканирование файла (в консоли для вебмастеров) – это ускорит индексацию.

Ну и мелочь но все же

Так как на сайте много страниц, нужно бы актуализировать внутренние ссылки. 
Да, там будет редирект, но при общих равных, конкурент будет выше, если у вас 100500 внутренних ссылок с редиректами,  а у конкурента без.

И еще, это позволит избежать появления "битых" внутренних ссылок.